# How do you make a Texture Altas

Tags: textures, texture-mapping, texture-atlas

How do developers make Texture Atlas'?  Do they do it by hand?

I'm using Unity3d, I think they have something about scripting an atlas, but I don't know how or understand to do it.

Can somebody explain the process of making Texture Atlas? If possible a way to script my own or provide a freeware alternative.

Answer (score 0):

How can create texture atlas by hand via any of the third-party libraries available out there.

I would recommend this tutorial to start with: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Rectangle_Placement.shtml

Later you can move on to the more advanced code: http://clb.demon.fi/projects/even-more-rectangle-bin-packing